# How can I add 2 other git repositories as branches for my repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have 3 folders (each a git repo), say `Dev` `UAT` and `Prototype`. I want my `Dev` branch to be master, and I want those repositories to appear as branches.

So far I was thinking of linking a remote to each folder (with its git inside), and then somehow merge them with the `--unrelated` tag. How would I do this for 3 branches? I tried but none worked.

To clarify, when I do `git branch` in the `Dev` folder, I want to see `master` `Prototype` and `UAT` to apppear as branches. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are describing is called `git submodule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the other repositories as branches in your existing *Dev* git repo then you can do the following

```
cd <Dev Path>

git remote add UATremote <Path to UAT Folder Repo>
git fetch UATremote
git checkout -b UAT UATremote/master

git remote add PROTOremote <Path to ProtoType Folder Repo>
git fetch PROTOremote
git checkout -b Prototype PROTOremote/master
```

And then optionally clean up the remotes:

```
git remote rm UATremote
git remote rm PROTOremote
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do and what I did so far. If I do `git checkout -b UAT HEAD`, is that bad? I did HEAD for each of them, I think this is where I went wrong.

Comment: It's not bad it depends on what you want to achieve. If you run `git checkout -b UAT HEAD` then a new branch will be created and checkout out using code wherever your current local HEAD is pointed. Instead I suspect you want new branches using the code from your other git repositories? You can do this by using their master branches into your `Dev` folder. I.e: `git checkout -b NewBranch myRemote/master`

Comment: Also you can run `git branch -d UAT` to remove the branch you created before

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Do I have to do a `git pull` anywhere? No, right? I initially had a `git pull` as well, but I feel like that would merge the branch (UAT) into master (Dev). I might ask  you more questions tomorrow while testing. thanks a lot! Very helpful.

Comment: Well you can do a git pull instead if you want to fetch and merge the remote into Dev master or a new branch. For example this achieves the same: `$ git checkout master`, `$ git checkout -b Prototype` `$ git pull PROTOremote master`. If by accident your local prototype branch has commits on it that you want to keep you can optionally rebase your commits on your local Prototype branch ahead of the upstream ProtoRemote, or your git log mentions that you performed a merge into your Prototype branch.

Answer (score 1):

Although submodules is the basic answer, I recommend you don't do that because I think you are trying to twist a tool the wrong way.

You want different environments, yes that is common to most shops, including the one I work in and all the others I know.

I recommend you have one master branch and one repository.

When you release different versions you can tag the releases with a version using a common versioning system

Comment: Oh yes, you should contribute to change it if you have the feeling that your company is doing things wrong and produce a lot of waste. Feel free to look at deployment tools also where packages are built one time and deployed on each environments. That's better and more sustainable practices.

Comment: Yes you can't change the company workflow.  What you can do is make the case.  Not a 2 minute conversation but a full-out 'I believe in quality and basic engineering principles'.  Do this in private 1 on 1 with the folks in authority.  At the same time look frantically for a new job and use the same reason when asked why to want to leave your current job / what you are looking for in a new job - your attitude will be respected at professional shops.

Comment: The main selling point?  Well yes you could do the company workflow but does that mean the company is going to maintain this, not be able to use other tools that don't use this oddball approach, etc.  The company can do this today no problem, surviving and growing however will be hard.

Comment: We are converting from TFS to Git, that is why this is happening.

Comment: If you are converting then NOW is the time to get the new workflow working correctly for the technology it uses.

Answer (score 0):

You simply add new remote

```
git remote add remote2 <url>
```

and now you can checkout any branch form any given remote to your repository.

Comment: How do I do the checkout? Simply `git checkout remote2`?

Comment: yes. if you have the same name you will have to use the remote name, try and you will get it in no time

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are describing use of `submodules`. You use them in scenarioes when you want to keep a repository within another repository. Such requirement may occur when you want to keep a library or an APi you use on a project updated across all contributors.

In order to add a `submodule` to your current repository use

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Where  is the URL you grab from GitHub or whatever. Remember `submodules` are simply repositories so workflow applies... To begin working on your repo within a repo you need to navigate into it like you'd normally do in `bash`

**VERY IMPORTANT**

When working with submodules you **DO NOT** start on a branch automatically. This has to be done manually, so don't forget to do `git checkout master` when you are in your `submodule` prior to any work...

Comment: This is very interesting.